# Divergent sequence with term difference less than 1/n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following exercise:

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence. Is it true that if $|s_{n+1}-s_n|<\frac1n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $(s_n)$ converges?

I think the answer is no, and I've been trying to find a divergence sequence with the above property, but I can't think of any.

Comment: What about the a sequence with $s_{n + 1} - s_n = \frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: It's actually possible for $s_n$ to be dense in $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.  For example, take
$$
s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1}
$$
you could also do something clever with $s_n = \log(n+1)$ along these lines.

Answer (score 3):

edit:
Take $s_n=\log{n}$ then $\log(n+1)-\log{n}=\log(1+1/n)<1/n$ for sufficiently large $n$. But clearly $s_n$ doesn't converge .

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: Yes ,you are right . See the edited answer .